# SQL Insert Into problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used INSERT INTO to combine columns from two tables into a whole new table. The results were not what I expected to be, data is split between my two Insert Into outputs. The point is to pull employee id and names from one table and time clock interactions from another and get them to display in an excel sheet. Guess I am trying to find the best way to get this done.

INSERT INTO split results][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pUmx.png)

Comment: You need join join the two tables together 1st and then use that as your insert into.  I assume employeeID is the Foreign Key to timeclockInteractions; so employee must be joined to timeclockinteractions.  That result is what you want to export to excel.

Comment: We can't really help you with your code if you don't post your code. Have a look at the much posted [Spaghetti DBA post](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for formulating a question.

Comment: Alright. I need to learn those. I will try that out. Much thanks.

Comment: One other option would be using `merge`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT * INTO #TEMPTable
SELECT T1.employee_id, T1.last_name, T1.first_name, T2.action_time, T2.action_date, T2.shift_start, T2.action_type 
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.employee_id = T2.employee_ID

SELECT * from #TEMPTable

DROP TABLE #TEMPTable
```

OR Just

```
SELECT T1.employee_id, T1.last_name, T1.first_name, T2.action_time, T2.action_date, T2.shift_start, T2.action_type 
FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.employee_id = T2.employee_ID
```

Then, export the results to a .CSV file.

Comment: This has given me alot of syntax errors Trying to post a snip but not able to

Comment: Well, since you didn't give actual table names, or table schema definitions, I merely provided a sample type of query that could be used, after you replaced my table names and column names with the actual ones.  I don't even know if the timeclock interactions table has an employee_id column, but you would need a column to join the first table with the second table.  There is no way my sample queries would compile against your database unless I'm psychic or something :-)

Comment: I admit there is a lack of information given, but you have enough. I appreciate the work and tried to use it. I would think the problem may be that I am using MSSQL 2008 and I failed to mention that. You were right about the 2 employee id columns, that is why that is the first column that I have an interaction with. My problem simply is the syntax errors. It does not like that I am specifying t2 columns. Everything else seems to be fine with <SELECT t1.employee, t1.first_name.... just not that second table

Comment: Opps!  My mistake.  I've corrected the syntax to add T2 to the JOIN statement.  (slaps own forehead in frustration).  Otherwise, the syntax should be great for MSSQL 2008.

Comment: Now I am sure that it isn't as easy as I want... Will this update with the information from the other two tables? Or do I need to update it daily?

Comment: Originally, you said that you wanted to pull the data from the two tables and then display it in a spreadsheet.  So, yes, you would need to run this query whenever you want to update your spreadsheet.  A manual process.  Or, you could create a database View out of the query statement.  Then, you could create a report, such as a Reporting Services report that would display the contents of the View whenever the user wants to run it.